# Mac OS app, sandbox with command line tool?

Tags: macos, sandbox, command-line-tool

I've made an app which includes a command-line tool. I have enabled the app's sandbox, and tested that it works. I've also code-signed both the app and the command line tool.

But when I upload the app to iTunes, I received a email telling me "App sandbox not enabled".

Apparently I need to set entitlement file of key `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` with `true` value, and list the executables: `/Contents/MacOS/myApp` and  `/contents/Frameworks/x86/myCommandLineTool`.

I'm sure I've enabled sandbox in Xcode, so I thought the problem was with the command line tool.

How can I enable sandbox for command line tool? Or is there a specific folder I should put the tool? Any suggestions welcome - I have been troubled by it for several days.

Comment: thanks for andrewdotnich's edit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same issue and after some search, trial & error, this is what worked for me:

1. create an entitlement file - for me it was just com.apple.security.inherit set to YES. I created this file in xcode itself.
2. Now sign this commandline tool using the command:

   ```
   codesign --entitlements ./entitlements.plist -s "copy & paste your certificate from keychain" ./commandlinetool
   ```
3. Just to be sure, check using this command:

   ```
   codesign --display --entitlements - ./commandlinetool
   ```
4. This tool was already included in the project. So just compile, archive & submit

The status is now 'waiting for review'.

Comment: I'm unsure how copy-pasting from keychain would work.  When I right-click and select copy, nothing is added to my clipboard.  Is there something obvious I'm overlooking?

Comment: @BenWest Literally copy the name of the certificate. For example: "Mac Developer: John Smith (1231231231)"

Comment: One more thing I want to add is to make sure that your command line tool is not located in the Resource folder. After struggling a lot, I figured out after reading code sign guide that tools should be installed/located in specific locations .i.e., MacOS, Helpers, etc folders. Hope this is a valuable addition.