# Codesign CLI tools in app bundle with Mavericks

Tags: code-signing, osx-mavericks

I've had an app submission rejected from the Mac App Store with the vague feedback that it's incorrectly sandboxed. The app includes a couple of command-line helper tools bundled with it. While I've asked Apple for more details, I've also run across the more stringent requirements for code-signing (all executable code in the app bundle must be code-signed).

It was my understanding that using `codesign --deep` would recursively walk my app bundle and sign all Mach-O executables with the same set of entitlements, so I thought this would take care of the CLI tools.

However, when I attempt to verify the signature on one of the CLI tools, I get this output:

> MyApp.app/Contents/lib/helper/helpertool: code object is not signed at
>   all.

So I'm a bit confused, especially when the app bundle itself passes verification:

> codesign --deep --verify --verbose=4 MyApp.app: valid on
>   disk,satisfies its Designated Requirement.

Can anyone suggest to me what I may be doing wrong here--why the CLI tools don't appear to be signed/sandboxed? Is there anything else I am missing here? (I build my app using a shell script rather than Xcode, but that shouldn't make a difference as far as I can tell.)

Comment: Are the command line helpers forks/spawned by the app?  If so, then I'm certain you **don't** want the same entitlements for the app and the command line utils.

Answer (score 1):

These links answered the question for me:

[Mac OS app, sandbox with command line tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821632/mac-os-app-sandbox-with-command-line-tool)

[How to sandbox a command line tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959958/how-to-sandbox-a-command-line-tool?rq=1)

Very cool.

Comment: Kevin - don't forget to mark your question answered.  It would help too, if you posted your solution in your answer.