# cocoa sandbox embedded command line not work

Tags: cocoa, nstask, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox, code-signing-entitlements

I have a third-party command line tool that launches from a main cocoa app which will be distributed in Mac App Store.

I need to sandbox the third-party command line tool, but when I run it (with NSTask), it crashes with error

> “Application Specific Signatures: Container object initialization failed: failed to get bundleid for app XXX”

(In the Console I can see the following error message).
Here is what I do in the main cocoa app:

```
NSTask* task          = [[NSTask alloc]init];
NSString* commandPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"command"];
task.launchPath       = commandPath;
[task setArguments:args];
[task launch];
```

And every time I run this, There’s a popup window appears with the information “OS X needs to repair your Library to run applications. Type youre password to allow this.” I’ve signed this command line tool using the command:

```
codesign --entitlements ./XXX.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: XXX" ./commandlinetool
```

To make sure, I double checked it using this command:

```
codesign --display --entitlements - ./commandlinetool
```

Here is the information :

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I also checked through this command:

```
codesign --display --verbose=4 XXX
```

and got this information:

```
Identifier=com.XXX.XXX.XXX
Format=Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=75902 flags=0x0(none) hashes=3786+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=24fdcb9b5444a91f60xxxxx3a66bafa7030109e63fb1c
Signature size=4347
Authority=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: XXX
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=May 10, 2014, 12:04:34 PM
Info.plist=not bound
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=216
```

I also try to add an info.plist file to the command line tool, stepped by this chapter [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959958/how-to-sandbox-a-command-line-tool) but nothing happened, the result of Info.plist still is "no bound".

How to sandbox third-party command line tool and how to add an info.plist file to the command line tool? Did I miss something?
Is there anybody can help me on this? Any help or pointer will be very much appreciated.

Comment: is the app to be distributed with Mac App Store?

Comment: Yes, is there a problem?

Comment: No not at all. I changed the tags accordingly to give your question some more visibility.

Comment: I would recommend looking at examples of what other MAS apps have done in a similar situation. Do you use any apps that do what you're trying to do?

Comment: Could you resolve this issue? I'm facing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's been so long I haven't noticed this question, but there still someone ask me how to do.

According to the Apple development documentation.

[If your app employs a child process created with either the posix_spawn function or the NSTask class, you can configure the child process to inherit the sandbox of its parent. However, using a child process does not provide the security afforded by using an XPC service.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW15)

So, you should sign your embedded command line with this entitlements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now your app works!